Transferring a regression with ARIMA error model from R to Excel (formula help)
I'm trying to translate an ARIMA model into an Excel spreadsheet for calculations for something I'm studying.
The model is a ARIMA(4,1,0) that I used the forecast::Arima function in R to fit.
The output coefficients are
ar1:.2499 ar2:-.0060 ar3:-.1258 ar4:-.0046.
The xreg coefficient is -29.5243.
No matter what I try, I can't seem to get the formula right and the output doesn't line up. I think what I'm confused on is if I include a difference factor in the ARIMA errors, I'm not sure how to account for that (or if I have to) on the back end.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is no Arima function in base R.  Are you perhaps referring to a user-written library?  Or do you mean arima?

I'm using the "Arima" (capital a) function from the forecast package I believe.

In ARIMA(p,d,q) the differencing is always done first. Next to the raw data in excel (let's call it Y), create a column of data that is the change in Y (let's call it DY). Then, a column that is the first lag of DY, another that is the second lag of DY, etc. You can apply your coefficients to these columns (e.g., the ar1 coefficient would multiply the first difference of DY), and sum them. This will give you the model predictions for the change in Y. Finally, for any time period, you can add the actual Y to the predicted change in Y to get the predicted value of Y.

If you are using a function from the forecast package, you can make that clear using the syntaxis forecast::Arima
